# Python retries on all exceptions except a list of exceptions

Tags: python, retry-logic

Most guides & posts talk about the reverse where you decide which exceptions to retry on ahead of time. Perhaps I'm thinking about it the wrong way, but for example, I'm trying to get google service account credentials

```
 def get_google_credentials(self, google_creds_dict):        
     SCOPES = [
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     ]
        
     credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(google_creds_dict, scopes=SCOPES)
        
     return credentials
```

Since I know it returns a `ValueError`, I think I'd only want to retry on other exceptions

Comment: just add multiple exceptions - `try: do stuff; except ValueError: pass; except IndexError: do stuff`

Answer (score 1):

Use an `except <type>:` block for the specific exceptions you want to pass through, and then a general `except:` for all the ones that should be retried. Then put this in a `while` loop to get it to keep trying.

```
import time

def get_google_credentials(self, google_creds_dict):   
    SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    ]

    while True:
        try:
            return service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(google_creds_dict, scopes=SCOPES)
        except ValueError as e:
            # pass ValueError through
            raise e from None
        except:
            # retry on any other error
            time.sleep(1)
```